# restore uncommitted files from bazaar which have been inadvertently deleted elsewhere

Tags: bazaar, recover

I have tried diligently to find bazaar user groups. I tried pressing the community tab on their website. There seem to be only mailing lists, but where does one start? The title says it all. I have tried revert, but since it was uncommitted, it did not work. The names of the files in question show up on 'bzr status' under 'missing'. the other files show up under 'added'. I am a bazaar rank beginner, and though I knew about commit, just forgot to do it after adding. Are the files well and truly lost, or is there a way to get them back? In the list you presented before answering, the only one which comes close to my situation is: "How can I un-delete an uncommitted", but unfortunately is for svn, not bazaar. This is my last shred of hope. I have held off doing commit now because I am afraid of losing the little which remains, since Bazaar says the are missing.

Answer (score 1):

If `bzr status` says `missing` rather than `removed`, then the files were deleted from disk after they had been added but before a commit happened, I'm afraid.

Under these circumstances, `bzr revert` cannot help you; it will restore the working directory (or part of it) to the state of a specific revision. Without a commit, there is no revision to revert from, because the system has no record of your files.

If you have backups for your system, you may still be able to recover files from there.